# A condition under which $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ which can also be thought of as $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ in the usual way. $f$ is $C^{(2)}$ on open connected domain $\Omega$ and ${Df|_z}^T {Df|_z} = \lambda(z) I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $Df|_z$ denotes the vector derivative of $f$ at $z$.

Under these conditions, I must show that either $f$ or $\bar f$ is analytic. I have a proof but it seems too strong because it does not use the fact that the domain $\Omega$ is connected or $f$ being $C^{(2)}$ and it concludes that $f$ is analytic without caring about $\bar{f}$.

What is wrong with my proof below?

We must show existence of $\lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h}$ for every $z \in \Omega$. By differentiability of $f$ we have $$f(z + h) - f(z) = Df|_z \cdot h + E(h)$$ where $|E(h)|/|h| \rightarrow 0$ as $|h| \rightarrow 0$ and the equation is interpreted in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Now we can interpret this equation in $\mathbb{C}$ and divide both sides by $h$.

$$\frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h} = \frac{Df|_z \cdot h}{h} + \frac{E(h)}{h}$$
So we only must prove the existence of $\lim_{|h|\rightarrow 0}\frac{Df|_z \cdot h}{h}$ since the other term goes to $0$.

This is almost trivial since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda(z)}}Df|z$ is orthonormal and hence it is a rotation matrix by some angle $\theta$. Hence $$\frac{Df|_z \cdot h}{h} = \sqrt{\lambda(z)}he^{i \theta}/h = \sqrt{\lambda(z)}e^{i \theta}$$

and the limit of a constant is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that $D_f$ need not be a rotation if the determinant is $-1$. Then we would argue about $D_{\bar f}$ being a rotation since it has the opposite determinant.

$C^{(1)}$ suffices for the determinant to be constant throughout the domain $\Omega$ since the determinant would be continuous and $\Omega$ connected.